# Samba allow SMB1 protocol for a single IP only

Tags: samba, smb-conf

I have an old network printer in my Linux network supporting SMB1 only. How can I limit the potential security issue to this IP only? Enabling the SMB1 protocol in the  [global] section of smb.conf is working as expected but is not what I want. Is there any way to limit the SMB1 version to a single IP address within the smb.conf or is there any better mechanism to archive this?

Comment: Run a separate SMB instance, it will probably need its own interface or at least separate IP to bind to.

Comment: Retiring the printer would be the most responsible solution.

Comment: Ok, I see it's not that easy. I will interface the old printer via USB and a raspberry supporting latest protocol versions. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 3):

SMB1 and SMB3 use same network ports and it is impossible to allow SMB1 only to specific IP with either smb.conf or TCP firewall.

You need to run separate smb instance as **NiKiZe** mentioned. Another approach would be to look at “Application” layer firewalls,  which may distinguish SMB1 and SMB3.